# translate month name response

Tags: java, oracle, format, locale, navicat

I have a table named CREATED_AT 
I wrote a query and receive the response like this :

`Score     D
27     01
17     02
80     03
55     06`

this is my query :

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) as scores,to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MONTH') as  d  
FROM C_SCORES 
WHERE USER_ID =201 and to_char(CREATED_AT, 'YYYY') ='1398' 
GROUP BY to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MONTH');
```

the entity code is :

```
    public class ScoreCategorizeWithMonth {

        private int Scores;
        private int month;
    private String monthfa;


 public String getMonthfa() {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                monthfa = "فروردین";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthfa = "اردیبهشت";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthfa = "خرداد";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthfa = "تیر";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthfa = "مرداد";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthfa = "شهریور";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthfa = "مهر";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthfa = "آبان";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthfa = "آذر";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthfa = "دی";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthfa = "بهمن";
                break;
            case 12:
                monthfa = "اسفند";
            default:
                monthfa = "";
        }



        return monthfa;
    }

    }
```

this code is in the controller :

```
 @GetMapping(value = "score-Categorize-months")
    public List<ScoreCategorizeWithMonth> scoreCategorizedWithMonths()
    {
        return   iScoresSrv.scoreCategorizeWithMonths(userInfo.getUserId());
    }
```

my question is  :

2- my response is the months that exist in database.how to show months  even its not in the database

```
 {
    "scores": 27,
    "month": 1,
    "monthfa": "فروردین"
  },
  {
    "scores": 17,
    "month": 2,
    "monthfa": "اردیبهشت"
  },
  {
    "scores": 84,
    "month": 3,
    "monthfa": "خرداد"
  },
  {
    "scores": 55,
    "month": 6,
    "monthfa": "شهریور"
  }
```

I want to show also the months of 4..5 with score=0

thanks

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and make sure they are clear and easy to understand. I removed all java related tags because I don't see how java is relevant here.

Comment: I think maybe I should add some   code in java to my view code .. why did you do that ? I am working with java :)  @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Then explain how your question relates to java and include relevant code. This question is both unclear and to broad.

Comment: Ok.I add some explanation .can you help me ? plz @JoakimDanielson

Comment: 1. using a localization resource system. You use the langage in the DB as a key and you can translate in any language (too long to explain how here). 2. Unclear,, 3.if the month doesn't exist in the DB, you will need to provide yourself a list of expected value and map with the `Score` if present. **Note that this can't be answered because there is to many question asking for totally different thing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add sume code in java to fill the indexes that are invalid . 
it was so easy to solve . but I was a bit confused and none of the answers didnt help me

```
 public List<ScoreCategorizedWithMonth> scoreCategorizeWithMonths(Long userId) {
        List<ScoreCategorizedWithMonth> monthCategory = scoreDao.scoreCategorizeWithMonths(userId);
        List<ScoreCategorizedWithMonth> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=1; i<=12;i++)
        {
            ScoreCategorizedWithMonth scoreCategorizedWithMonth = checkMonthCatIsExist(i, monthCategory);
            result.add(scoreCategorizedWithMonth);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private ScoreCategorizedWithMonth checkMonthCatIsExist(int month, List<ScoreCategorizedWithMonth> monthCategory) {
        for (ScoreCategorizedWithMonth cat:monthCategory) {
            if(cat.getMonth() == month){
                return cat;
            }
        }
        ScoreCategorizedWithMonth temp= new  ScoreCategorizedWithMonth();
        temp.setMonth(month);
        temp.setScores(0);
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 and 3: You can achieve with Following Query:

```
select sum(AMOUNT) as scores, month from  
(select AMOUNT ,to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MONTH') as month from C_SCORES WHERE USER_ID 
 =201 and to_char(CREATED_AT, 'YYYY') ='1398'
 union
 select 0 as AMOUNT, Month from
 (SELECT 1 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 2 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 3 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 4 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 5 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 6 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 7 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 8 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 9 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
 UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH) TBL1) TBL2
 group by month;
```

Just Replace 1-12 as the month value of yours

Comment: each month  has its value.. actually I want it as a report that how many score   the user has earned

Comment: @maede What do you mean by each month has it's value?

Comment: exactly can you let me know what do you mean by each month has its value and as per your query you are filtering records where user_id = 201 so it is going to give you record for the user with id  201

Comment: [Err] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected  I tried your answer .this has error

Comment: I think so your database is an oracle and I have tried this query on MySQL and it worked. can you please post your query

Comment: @NikhilTiwari  This is my query :  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) as scores,to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MM') as d FROM C_SCORES   WHERE  USER_ID =201 and to_char(CREATED_AT, 'YYYY') ='1398' 
 
GROUP BY to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MM') ORDER BY to_char(CREATED_AT, 'MM')

Comment: can you please explain how to write it on  oracle ?

Comment: I have updated the question .please take a look . @NikhilTiwari

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties files...

This link provide one example of many:
http://zetcode.com/java/resourcebundle/

in that tutorial, the `'words.properties'` is your default and fallback language file, and the `words_de.properties`, and `words_sk.properties` are for customized translated language

In this line: `source.setBasenames("messages/words");` he tried to pass translation files to the algorithm.

and using `messageSource.getMessage("w1", null, Locale.GERMAN)` he fetch the desired language....

Note that `sk` in `words_sk.properties` is language iso code, which in case for persian is `fa`, and for english is `en`...

Some system use localization too, which they define custom character and formatting, which i'm not sure if this algorithm support those kind of naming ... which you pass an extra parameter: `fa-IR` , or `en-US`

To be honest i didn't look deep, but since i used it years ago, it is the principle.

Comment: I added month.properties  and month_fa.properties      and in setDate() method added this code :   ResourceBundle persian=ResourceBundle.getBundle("month_fa",new Locale("fa","IR"));
        persian.getLocale();

Comment: error : Can't find bundle for base name month_fa, locale fa_IR

Comment: this line says where too look for the file: `source.setBasenames("messages/words");` to be honest im not sure about the file structure, as each IDE provide different file structure

Comment: I updated the question please take a look  @deadManN